# Are legal issues on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I wonder if legal topics [like this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42621/how-to-report-hotel-booking-fraud) from today are on-topic. I am worried that we may open a huge can of worms with that.

I am torn over this myself however. While it's surely good to get help what to do when your passport is stolen (in my opinion not a legal topic) I am wondering how far this can go towards "my account on this travel website was stolen"...

Opinions?

Answer (score 5):

Asking opinions is off topic, please see the help...I kid ;) But seriously, you're right, we don't want to get too far into resolving legal matters.  In this case, I think answers should cover general - what happens, if it's on credit card, get the charge cancelled (you can show the bank the double charge), and so on.  But certainly not stuff like "Under Russian Law, companies must..." and so on.

Having hotels unexpectedly charge you is a fairly common travel problem (I had one block my entire credit card once for a single night's stay!).

If it comes to 'my account on website x is was stolen', well that's off topic as it's a something that website can only help with, and is a software/security issue, not a travel one ;)

Comment: Asking opinions is not a topic. Subjectivity is bad for SE sites and not welcome. Not everything unwelcome on the site is about topic. We shouldn't really use "off topic" for all reasons a post is wrong for the site since it has a specific meaning.

Comment: @hippietrail yeah, it was a quick sentence as a joke, my choice of words wasn't perfect, I agree :)

Comment: Just trying to stamp out this misusage whenever I see it, don't want to take the thread off-topic. Oops (-: